# Disable li using Dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am using dojo script to create custom dropdown list. when I create dropdown,

```
dojo.forEach(tags, function(tag) {
              var option = dojo.create("option", {
                                     innerHTML: tag.name    
                                     });
                                dojo.place(option, Select);
                            });

                    });
```

I create this drop-down to achieve the autocomplete.

Now the problem is I would like some of the opitions disabled, so user cannot select them.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK and was trying there is not such a possibility. I think it makes very little sense to mix autocomplete with disabled values. Possible solutions:

1. Get rid of autocomplete feature and use `dijit.form.Select` or native `Select`, both works fine with `<option disabled="true"></option>`.
2. Use `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` and don't add or dynamically remove options you want to disable.

Please note that `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` and `dijit.form.ComboBox` are primarily designed to work with model based on API of `dojo.data` and from Dojo 1.7 also `dojo.store`. You should update Model (dojo.data/dojo.store) because View (FilteringSelect/ComboBox) is observing the model and updates UI when needed. See my [jsFiddle examples](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/hmKTM/).

N.B.: If you are not familiar with `dojo.data` API and you can use the latest version of Dojo don't bother to dive into dojo.data API and start with `dojo.store`. It's terribly wrong and complicated way to manage model via dojo.data.